# Robo3T will only insert the first JSON object but not the second?

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I am trying to insert a document into a collection in Robo3T. I have a script like:

```
db.permissions.insert({
    "_id" : "INS-SH-V",
    "name" : "View Sharing Functionality",
},
{
    "_id" : "INS-SH-U",
    "name" : "Manage Sharing Functionality",
});
```

But it will only insert the "INS-SH-V" document but not the second. I have tried putting `.insertMany` or `{multi:true}` in the end too but nothing seems to be working.

When I do `insertMany` it returns something like this:

```
db.getCollection('permissions').insertMany({
    "_id" : "INS-SH-V",
    "name" : "View Sharing Functionality",
    "description" : "Access to view Email and Schedule windows in Insights",
},
{
    "_id" : "INS-SH-U",
    "name" : "Manage Sharing Functionality",
    "description" : "Access to send emails and schedule jobs in Insights",
})
```

[image: error]

When I use `{multi:true}` or basically

```
db.getCollection('permissions').insert({
    "_id" : "INS-SH-V",
    "name" : "View Sharing Functionality",
},
{
    "_id" : "INS-SH-U",
    "name" : "Manage Sharing Functionality",
}, {multi:true})
```

It will only add the first document "INS-SH-V" but not the other.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the [documentation about `db.collection.insertMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertMany/index.html).

> The insertMany() method has the following syntax:
>
> ```
> db.collection.insertMany(
>    [ <document 1> , <document 2>, ... ],
>    {
>       writeConcern: <document>,
>       ordered: <boolean>
>    }
> )
> ```

`insertMany` expects an array.

```
db.getCollection('permissions').insert([{
    "_id" : "INS-SH-V",
    "name" : "View Sharing Functionality",
},
{
    "_id" : "INS-SH-U",
    "name" : "Manage Sharing Functionality",
}])
```

Answer (score -1):

So after a bit of digging, I found out that I have to pass the first argument as an array. This was the final result that worked:

```
db.getCollection('permissions').insert([{
    "_id" : "INS-SH-V",
    "name" : "View Sharing Functionality",
},
{
    "_id" : "INS-SH-U",
    "name" : "Manage Sharing Functionality",
}])
```